# VC: How to split big .lib into small .lib files

Tags: c, windows, static-libraries, visual-c++

Environment: VC, Windows.
I have a big .lib file, aaa.lib, created by third party. I have no source code. I need to build myselves static library bbb.lib, which use few functions from aaa.lib. Because of some business issue, I have to hide aaa.lib to my customer. So I use this command to 'merge' aaa.lib into bbb.lib.

```
LIB /OUT:bbb.lib mycode.lib aaa.lib
```

It works, except bbb.lib is too big. How could I specify part of aaa.lib when I do the 'merge'? Thanks. I know there is another post about .lib split, but it's not for windows.

I tried these commands to extract a function, but don't work. Take WSAStartup() in ws2_32.lib as example:

```
LIB ws2_32.lib /extract:__imp__WSAStartup@8
```

LINK : warning LNK4014: cannot find member object _*imp*_WSAStartup@8

```
LIB ws2_32.lib /extract:WSAStartup
```

LINK : warning LNK4014: cannot find member object WSAStartup

Comment: The linker should be smart enough to only link with the actual functions (actually, object files) used, not put the whole library in the executable. So the size of a library should not matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you use really FEW functions from particular objects you can extract object files with

```
LIB library /EXTRACT:member /OUT:objectfile
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/889z8z58%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for details.

For list of all objects in the library you can use:

```
LIB library /LIST
```

Comment: I tried these commands to extract a function, but don't work. Take WSAStartup() in ws2_32.lib as example: 

    LIB ws2_32.lib /extract:__imp__WSAStartup@8
   LINK : warning LNK4014: cannot find member object _imp_WSAStartup@8 

    LIB ws2_32.lib /extract:WSAStartup
   LINK : warning LNK4014: cannot find member object WSAStartup

Comment: This function extracts object, not the function. Function extraction is impossible because apart the function objects contain data and bss section with global/static data can be used by function.